# Importing local json in main.js in Svelte

Tags: json, svelte

What is the pattern for importing JSON into Svelte's main.js file?

I'm trying:

```
import App from './App.html';
const dataset = require('./../posts.json');

console.log(dataset);

const app = new App({
  target: document.body,
  data: dataset
});

export default app;
```

But this does not resolve as JSON cannot be imported as an es6 module.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Svelte isn't involved in this process — it's entirely up to your bundler. If you're using Rollup, you'll need to add the [rollup-plugin-json](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-json) plugin to your rollup.config.js file.

Comment: moved to [@rollup/plugin-json](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json#readme)

Comment: I use SvelteKit and import `.json` to `svelte.config.js` I get type error, unknown file extension `.json` How to fix?