# Trouble loading json file to html using svelte

Tags: html, json, svelte

i am new to svelte and i have to use it for my intern's work.

I have my local json file and trying to it to my HTML. I have been searching everywhere but could not get the answer.

I tried to do this:

cat.svelte:

```
<script>
import {onMount} from "svelte";

let data = [];

onMount(async ()=>{
    const response = await fetch("./table_schema_name.json");
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)

});

</script>
<p>displa</p>
{#each data as item}
<div>
    <p>{item.table_name}</p>
    <p>display</p>
</div>
{/each}
```

and my JSON File looks like this:

table_schema_name.json

```
[
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a1"},
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a2"},
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a3"}, 
    {"table_schema": "b", "table_name": "b1"},
     {"table_schema": "b", "table_name": "b2"}
]
```

error that i am getting from the console.

```
cat.svelte:7 GET http://localhost:3000/table_schema_name.json 404 (Not Found)
cat.svelte:9 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Appreciate it so much. Really need to display the json file in HTML badly using SVELTE!

Comment: [Importing local json in main.js in Svelte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063652/importing-local-json-in-main-js-in-svelte)

Comment: tried this. but not working. bumped into another error while doing tht @NikitaMadeev

Comment: is your json file available on your server ? (is it in the public folder) because that is where it tries to get it from

Comment: Yes it is in the public folder in my project directory

Comment: if you just point your browser to `http://localhost:3000/table_schema_name.json` does it show up ? this looks more like a problem with your server than svelte itself

Comment: I am creating a codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-yonath-j37v2?file=/App.svelte) for your code. The JSON you provide as example seems to be incorrect. Thus if you get a 404 error, the problem should not come from Svelte but from the path needed to reach `table_schema_name.json`

Comment: I got this error when i put the json file under the same folder in src. If i did this way, the error is : 'table_schema_name.json' is imported by src\routes\catalog.svelte, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency on the server and client side. And on the service worker:internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'table_schema_name.json' Require stack: - C:\Users\t_binta\Desktop\ICM\portal__sapper__\dev\server\server.js

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the json, I recommand you to import it locally just like that :

```html
<script>
  import data from "./path/to/table_schema_name.json";
</script>

{#each data as item}
<div>
    <p>{item.table_name}</p>
    <p>display</p>
</div>
{/each}
```

The bundler will directly inject it in the generated code so there will be no issues with the server ;)

Comment: If i did this way, the error is : 'table_schema_name.json' is imported by src\routes\catalog.svelte, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency on the server and client side. And on the service worker:internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'table_schema_name.json'    
Require stack:
- C:\Users\t_binta\Desktop\ICM\portal\__sapper__\dev\server\server.js

Comment: @skylight Are you sure that you import it with the correct path? Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wing-yc25l?file=/src/App.svelte) that works completely fine using the right path. Please provide in details the structure of the project and how you tried to import the `.json`.

Comment: apparently, my json is not in the server. Im trying to put in my server which i have problem hosting my json file to get the url

Comment: If you make it works locally then there would be no issue with the server (the bundler will inject the `json` directly in the generated `.min.js` file). So what do you get if you tried it this way locally?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by myself after thorough searches on Internet.

Basically,i moved my table_schema_name.json to static folder. By moving it to the static folder, i can access the JSON file via the URL.

So i change my code from:

```
onMount(async ()=>{
    const response = await fetch("./table_schema_name.json");
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data)

});
```

To:

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

let data = [];

onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/table_schema_name.json');
    data = await res.json();
});
```

I wished that i found out about this earlier as i have wasted hours to solve this. Hope my answer helps those who are facing same issues as me.

Comment: Still not a good idea :/ Why make a local fetch if you can directly import it? It spare you an async call.

Comment: For now, i am using a local file for development. But in the later part, i will need to fetch the data from AWS

Comment: Why not tell this part earlier ?